# update fields mysql table with value from other row for the same product id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to update a database table with value that is used in another row.
I have a database with 4000 products, for every product there are 3 rows, 1 for every language (i work with 3 languages).

Now i need to copy the product title from the dutch language into the title field from the English product row and the French product row for the same product id. Some title field in English and Frensh are empty, but not al off them are empty.

So I have this fields
product_id ; 
language_id ; 
product_title

Anyone can help me with the sql i need to have to do this for all my 4000 products?

Thank you, kind regards
Pete

ps_product_lang is the name of the product table
the database is MySQL

```
id_product  int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL     
id_shop int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI 1    
id_lang int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL     
description text    YES     NULL     
description_short   text    YES     NULL     
link_rewrite    varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
meta_description    varchar(255)    YES     NULL     
meta_keywords   varchar(255)    YES     NULL     
meta_title  varchar(128)    YES     NULL     
name    varchar(128)    NO  MUL NULL     
available_now   varchar(255)    YES     NULL     
available_later varchar(255)    YES     NULL
```

Comment: Describe your question with example.

Comment: Why do you want to COPY data? Can't you create a view which picks the best language instead?

Comment: thank you for your reply. no I just need to copy the product title from dutch to the other languages and so on for every product, so i need to run a query to do it, because it would be to much to open every product and change it. Kind regards Pete

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work.

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang p1
   SET name = 
       (SELECT name
          FROM (SELECT * FROM ps_product_lang) p2
         WHERE p2.`id_product` = p1.`id_product`
           AND p2.`id_lang` = 6)
 WHERE `id_lang` != 6
```

You need the extra nested select in there to prevent MySQL from reporting the following error:

Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank you for your reply. please can you explain the p1 an the p2 in you query? In my question i told that some title field in the other languages are not always empty, but even when they are not empty, they need to be over written with the value from the dutch title field. So I want to have the same title for all 3 languages after the query. Thank you for your information, kind regards Pete

Comment: p1 and p2 are just aliases for the product table to allow references to table columns in the child or parent query. I had the impression from your description that the non-empty titles should be left alone. I've revised the SQL accordingly though now.

Comment: John, I get an  error: 
#1054 - Unknown column 'p2.id_product' in 'where clause'

UPDATE ps_product_lang p1
   SET name = 
       (SELECT name
          FROM (SELECT * FROM ps_product_lang) p2
         WHERE `p2.id_product` = `p1.id_product`
           AND `p2.id_lang` = '6')
 WHERE `id_lang` != '6'

the database fields 
database = ps_product_lang
title = name
dutch language = 6

Comment: I think perhaps you want 'product_id' instead of 'id_product'? Otherwise, give me your table schema definition.

Comment: looks like i suck at this ;)  typing everything in one line,    
the database fields:  database = ps_product_lang,  title = name,  dutch language = 6, productID = id_product, languageID = id_lang

Comment: I'm still a bit confused... is ps_product_lang the name of your database or your product table. Assuming the latter, can you run the following in mysql (or your favourite query tool) and add the result to your question as additional info? 'desc ps_product_lang'

Comment: OK, have revised my SQL now.

Comment: sorry to say John  but still have the error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'p2.id_product' in 'where clause'

Comment: My mistake... I put the backticks in the wrong place

Comment: OK john it works nice, thank you very much, i learned somthing, it was more then 5 years since i did something in databases, thank you for your help. kind regards Pete